# B2G/android build error AudioPolicyService.cpp

Tags: android, c++, porting, firefox-os

I had this error while trying to port B2G/firefox os to a new (HTC desire HD) device. Can somebody explain what is the meaning of it or how to bypass it manually?
here is the full  [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/rbnYs90M). Thank you

```
target thumb C++: libaudioflinger <= frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: warning: missing initializer for member 'audio_policy_service_ops::set_voice_volume'
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: warning: missing initializer for member 'audio_policy_service_ops::move_effects'
frameworks/base/services/audioflinger/AudioPolicyService.cpp:1684: warning: missing initializer for member 'audio_policy_service_ops::set_fm_volume'
make: *** [out/target/product/ace/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libaudioflinger_intermediates/AudioPolicyService.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check if aps_ops is update as below:

> namespace {

```
struct audio_policy_service_ops aps_ops = {
    open_output           : aps_open_output,
    open_duplicate_output : aps_open_dup_output,
    close_output          : aps_close_output,
    suspend_output        : aps_suspend_output,
    restore_output        : aps_restore_output,
    open_input            : aps_open_input,
    close_input           : aps_close_input,
    set_stream_volume     : aps_set_stream_volume,
    set_stream_output     : aps_set_stream_output,
    set_parameters        : aps_set_parameters,
    get_parameters        : aps_get_parameters,
    start_tone            : aps_start_tone,
    stop_tone             : aps_stop_tone,
    set_voice_volume      : aps_set_voice_volume,
    move_effects          : aps_move_effects,
    set_fm_volume         : aps_set_fm_volume,
    load_hw_module        : aps_load_hw_module,
    open_output_on_module : aps_open_output_on_module,
    open_input_on_module  : aps_open_input_on_module,
};
```

> }; // namespace